# How to get all request headers?

Tags: delphi, com, twebbrowser

How can I get all the request headers with `OIBindInfo` or `IWinInetHttpInfo`? I use this in `Start` but the variable `Headers` or `RequestHeaders` is always empty?

Approach using `OIBindInfo`:

```
function THandler.Start(szUrl: PWideChar; OIProtSink:
IInternetProtocolSink; OIBindInfo: IInternetBindInfo; grfPI, dwReserved:
DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
var
    dwSize: ULONG;
    pszHeaders: POleStr;
    Headers: String;
begin
    OIBindInfo.GetBindString(BINDSTRING_HEADERS, @pszHeaders, 1, dwsize)
    Headers := PWideChar(pszHeaders); // weird result of Headers = ჸ
    CoTaskMemFree(pszHeaders);
    pszHeaders := nil;
    Result := INET_E_USE_DEFAULT_PROTOCOLHANDLER;
end;
```

Approach using `IWinInetHttpInfo`:

```
type
  THandler = class(TComObject, IInternetProtocol, IWinInetHttpInfo)
    private
      ServiceProvider: IServiceProvider;
      WinInetHttpInfo: IWinInetHttpInfo;
      URL: String;
      RequestHeaders: String;
      function QueryInfoEx(dwOption: DWORD; var Info: string): Boolean;
    protected
      function Start(szUrl: PWideChar; OIProtSink: IInternetProtocolSink;
        OIBindInfo: IInternetBindInfo; grfPI, dwReserved: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
      function Continue(const ProtocolData: TProtocolData): HResult; stdcall;
      function Abort(hrReason: HResult; dwOptions: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
      function Terminate(dwOptions: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
      function Suspend: HResult; stdcall;
      function Resume: HResult; stdcall;
      function Read(pv: Pointer; cb: ULONG; out cbRead: ULONG): HResult; stdcall;
      function Seek(dlibMove: LARGE_INTEGER; dwOrigin: DWORD;
        out libNewPosition: ULARGE_INTEGER): HResult; stdcall;
      function LockRequest(dwOptions: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
      function UnlockRequest: HResult; stdcall;
      function QueryInfo(dwOption: DWORD; Buffer: Pointer; var cbBuf, dwFlags, dwReserved: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
      function QueryOption(dwOption: DWORD; Buffer: Pointer; var cbBuf: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

function THandler.QueryInfoEx(dwOption: DWORD; var Info: string): Boolean;
var
  Buf: array[0..INTERNET_MAX_PATH_LENGTH] of AnsiChar;
  BufLength, dwReserved, dwFlags: Cardinal;
begin
    dwReserved := 0;
    dwFlags := 0;
    BufLength := INTERNET_MAX_PATH_LENGTH + 1;
    Result := not Boolean(WinInetHttpInfo.QueryInfo(dwOption, @Buf, BufLength, dwFlags, dwReserved));
    if Result then 
    Info := string(Buf);
end;

function THandler.Start(szUrl: PWideChar; OIProtSink:
IInternetProtocolSink; OIBindInfo: IInternetBindInfo; grfPI, dwReserved:
DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  OIProtSink.QueryInterface(IServiceProvider, ServiceProvider);
  OIProtSink.QueryInterface(IWinInetHttpInfo, WinInetHttpInfo);
  QueryInfoEx(HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS, RequestHeaders); // empty RequestHeaders
  Result := INET_E_USE_DEFAULT_PROTOCOLHANDLER;
end;
```

Neither are working!

Comment: Try with POleStr instead of POleStrArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking at the return value of `GetBindString()` to make sure it outputs any data.

Using a single `POleStr` is fine if you are retrieving a specific header, eg:

```
function THandler.Start(szUrl: PWideChar; OIProtSink: IInternetProtocolSink; OIBindInfo: IInternetBindInfo; grfPI, dwReserved: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
var
  MimeType: POleStr;
  Fetched: ULONG;
begin
  if Succeeded(OIBindInfo.GetBindString(BINDSTRING_POST_DATA_MIME, @MimeType, 1, Fetched)) then
  begin
    // use MimeType as needed...
    CoTaskMemFree(MimeType);
  end;
  Result := INET_E_USE_DEFAULT_PROTOCOLHANDLER;
end;
```

However, you are trying to retrieve multiple headers, so you need to use an array instead:

```
function THandler.Start(szUrl: PWideChar; OIProtSink: IInternetProtocolSink; OIBindInfo: IInternetBindInfo; grfPI, dwReserved: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
var
  Headers: array[0..255] of POleStr;
  Fetched, I: ULONG;
begin
  Fetched := 0;
  if Succeeded(OIBindInfo.GetBindString(BINDSTRING_HEADERS, @Headers[0], Length(Headers), Fetched)) then
  begin
    if Fetched > 0 then
    begin
      for I := 0 to Fetched-1 do
      begin
        // use Headers[I] as needed...
        CoTaskMemFree(Headers[I]);
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := INET_E_USE_DEFAULT_PROTOCOLHANDLER;
end;
```

That being said, [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that `BINDSTRING_HEADERS` is "Not currently supported".

Comment: Why is the `Headers` allocated before the `GetBindString` is even called? Have you actually tested this code? Because this won't work for any flag. Please update your code.

Comment: `Headers` is an array of pointers. `GetBindString()` does not allocate a new array, it merely fills in the existing array that it is given, that is why you have to pass in the array length as well. I do not know if it is possible to query how many headers are present so the array can be sized dynamically. No, I did not try the code, it is based on other examples I found.

Comment: Well before `GetBindString` is even called it is full of weird chars.

Comment: That is because the array is allocated on the stack, so it gets initialized with whatever random data is already on that section of the stack. Which is perfectly fine. You tell `GetBindString()` how many slots are in the array, and it returns how many slots it filled in, the rest do not matter.